# VPN, ICS and routing

Tags: vpn, route

My setup looks like this: I have a Win10 PC that is connected to the internet and connected to a VPN. I share the VPN network interface via ICS to the second network card that connects to my router and the rest of my network. Now I want to route one ip so I can access it from the rest of my network not through the VPN, but directly through the non-vpn connection.
I added a route on the PC running the VPN that allows me to connect to this one IP directly, not through the VPN:

`Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
...
    85.13.130.237  255.255.255.255    192.168.178.1   192.168.178.26     26`

this works on that PC. (That interface is the one directly connected to the internet)
Now I added a route for the network interface that the VPN connection is shared to (via ICS):

`Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
...
    85.13.130.237  255.255.255.255    192.168.178.1    192.168.137.1     26`

but when I run tracert it will still get routed through the VPN.
I tried researching windows routing but did not find good resources, if anyone could provide links etc I'm willing to learn!

Edit:
Here's the complete routing table:

`Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    192.168.178.1   192.168.178.26     25
          0.0.0.0        128.0.0.0      10.10.168.1    10.10.168.219      3
        10.0.75.0    255.255.255.0         On-link         10.0.75.1    271
        10.0.75.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.0.75.1    271
      10.0.75.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.0.75.1    271
      10.10.168.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     10.10.168.219    259
    10.10.168.219  255.255.255.255         On-link     10.10.168.219    259
    10.10.168.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     10.10.168.219    259
    85.13.130.237  255.255.255.255    192.168.178.1    192.168.137.1      2
    85.13.130.237  255.255.255.255    192.168.178.1  169.254.175.141     56
    85.13.130.237  255.255.255.255    192.168.178.1   192.168.178.26     26
    85.13.144.158  255.255.255.255    192.168.178.1   192.168.178.26     26
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        128.0.0.0        128.0.0.0      10.10.168.1    10.10.168.219      3
      169.254.0.0      255.255.0.0         On-link   169.254.175.141    311
  169.254.175.141  255.255.255.255         On-link   169.254.175.141    311
  169.254.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link   169.254.175.141    311
     172.18.84.96  255.255.255.240         On-link      172.18.84.97    271
     172.18.84.97  255.255.255.255         On-link      172.18.84.97    271
    172.18.84.111  255.255.255.255         On-link      172.18.84.97    271
  178.162.204.214  255.255.255.255      10.10.168.1    10.10.168.219      4
  178.162.204.227  255.255.255.255    192.168.178.1   192.168.178.26     25
    192.168.137.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.137.1    257
    192.168.137.1  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.137.1    257
  192.168.137.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.137.1    257
    192.168.178.0    255.255.255.0         On-link    192.168.178.26    281
   192.168.178.26  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.178.26    281
  192.168.178.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.178.26    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     10.10.168.219    259
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    192.168.178.26    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.137.1    257
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         10.0.75.1    271
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link   169.254.175.141    311
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      172.18.84.97    271
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     10.10.168.219    259
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.178.26    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.137.1    257
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.0.75.1    271
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link   169.254.175.141    311
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      172.18.84.97    271`

Internet facing interface is 192.168.178.26

VPN interface is 10.0.75.1

VPN is shared to this interface: 192.168.137.1

Answer (score 0):

What is the IP/mask of your "non VPN" and what is the IP of your VPN connection? Isn't it overlapping (at least partially)?

I can see the same gateway for the both records but as you can see there is different Interface. In case there is no other difference just VPN it seems to me like overlapping IP range so even the GW is the same the way how to reach the IP of the GW is just covered by VPN...

Could you please provide more network setting information or at least whole routing tables ? I am sorry I would just write comment but as a new user I cannot post the comment and only answer is available for me ;).

---

EDIT:
OK, I see the schema something like this (based on what you have wrote ;-) )...

[image: Network schema]

Based on routing table I see that your default GW (0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0) 192.168.178.1 is overtaken by the VPN (0.0.0.0/128.0.0.0 + 128.0.0.0/128.0.0.0) - by this is seems to me that VPN IP is 10.10.168.219/24 with GW 10.10.168.1. Your route on the PC sharing the connection is also correct :

`Network Destination  Netmask          Gateway        Interface     Metric
 85.13.130.237       255.255.255.255  192.168.178.1  192.168.178.26   26`

In case it is routing based on system routing table (if it is working as "regular router" over all network cards with ICS) we would be done on this PC. Other PC on internal network doesn't need any special route as the "main PC" is the most probably default GW for them (192.168.137.1). My doubts is related to the steps leading to share the internet connection in Windows 10. You are sharing specific connection / NIC to other specific connection / NIC. I am not sure if windows somehow doesn't limit the communication especially between these two connections. If so I am not sure if you could step out from this sendbox. In that case this would exactly explain the behaviour why on "main PC" it is working until on the "other PC" it is still pointing the VPN...

This route doesn't seems to me valid as 192.168.178.1 is not on 192.168.137.0/24 and the GW would be reachable on the connected network :

`Network Destination  Netmask          Gateway        Interface     Metric
 85.13.130.237       255.255.255.255  192.168.178.1  192.168.137.1   26`

Comment: I added the complete routing table.

Comment: Is there another way to basically share the VPN connection to the second NIC (to which the rest of my home network is connected)? I only used ICS because that was the only thing I knew how to do.
I guess it would then be easier to do what I initially set out to do.

Comment: I don't have opportunity to check it directly. But Win 10 Pro offer option of Hyper-V so functionality would be available... I would check keyword **IP routing** (e.g. this [link](https://www.keepthetech.com/2016/01/enable-ip-routing-on-windows10.html)) and then I would check **NAT** (e.g. this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/setup-nat-network)). This links are more just for inspiration as it is focused on another context but there are information which may help.I would not personally use Win for this but it doesn't mean it cannot be done.